# sending message from extension to tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm facing a problem sending messages from Chrome extension (popup.html) to a script injected in a selected tab. The code in popup.html is as follows:

```js
alert("sending MSG");
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(null, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
console.log(response.farewell); 
});
alert("MSG send");
```

The problem is that only the "sending MSG" alert appears but the second alert "MSG sent" doesn't show. It's like it's blocking the code.

Even when I use this function:

```js
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {  
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) { 
console.log(response.farewell); alert("MSG sent _ in");
                                         });
                        });
alert("MSG send _ out");
```

Here I get the same problem: the "MSG send _ out" is shown but the "MSG send _ in" isn't.
Please if someone has any idea about this problem let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you look popup inspector, you can see that your popup will have a runtime error, therefore the last `alert` is not working.

Solution is simple,
you should use `chrome.extension.sendMessage` instead of `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`,

```
alert("sending MSG");
chrome.extension.sendMessage(null, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell); 
});
alert("MSG send");
```